# Looking for assistance developing a vfp API to acumatica using VFP

Tags: acumatica, visual-foxpro, chilkat

I am developing an API interface to acumatica Using Visual FoxPro and ChilKat
Looking for sample code to get me started, has anyone done any work on this?

Comment: I am not familiar with either Visual FoxPro or Chilkat but are they able to make http request and play with session cookie?

Comment: Yes they can, new to http requests but I guess I will have to do a crash course